# How to copy audio file from application to phone local storage

Tags: audio, local-storage, fileapi, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm creating a tizen mobile web application and i'm very new to web applications, in which a list of audio files will display and user can listen to those songs and set as their ringtone, sms or notification tone.

I have all those files in application's raw folder.For setting ringtone audio file should be in phone's storage.
   Can anybody help me how to copy audio file to phone's local storage.

Answer (score 0):

In tizen 2.3 you can't copy audio file to ringtone storage.

in [device api filesystem document](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html)

> ringtones - the location for ringtones (read-only location)

if you just want copy file, use [copyTo](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html#File::copyTo).

Comment: I tried copyTo method.But it didn't work.I think that method will work copy files within the file system.